# Scons compiler path contains spaces

Tags: scons

I have a toolchain, not on the path, installed at a location containing spaces (`C:\Program Files\Some Compiler\`). I've tried:

```
env = Environment(
    MY_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT = R'C:\Program Files\Some Compiler\',
    MY_TOOLCHAIN_BIN = R'$MY_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT\bin',
)
env.Replace(
    CC = "$MY_TOOLCHAIN_BIN/gcc",
    CXX = "$MY_TOOLCHAIN_BIN/g++",
    OBJCOPY = "$MY_TOOLCHAIN_BIN/objcopy"
)

env.Program('main.cpp')
```

But I get the error

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How can I get scons to quote the spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems I need to mark them as `File`s:

```
env.Replace(
    CC = env.File("$MY_TOOLCHAIN_BIN/gcc"),
    CXX = env.File("$MY_TOOLCHAIN_BIN/g++"),
    OBJCOPY = env.File("$MY_TOOLCHAIN_BIN/objcopy")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the os style variables you are using with the `$`. Instead of  specifying them with the env.File() (Im surprised it handled the variables), you could consider some simple python code as follows:

```
import os

env = Environment(
    MY_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT = R'C:\Program Files\Some Compiler\',
    MY_TOOLCHAIN_BIN = R'$MY_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT\bin',
)
env.Replace(
    CC = os.path.join(os.environ["MY_TOOLCHAIN_BIN"], "gcc"),
    CXX = os.path.join(os.environ["MY_TOOLCHAIN_BIN"], "g++"),
    OBJCOPY = os.path.join(os.environ["MY_TOOLCHAIN_BIN"], "objcopy")
)
```